# Differential operators and commuting actions

Tags: rt.representation-theory

We have a smooth space $X$ with an action from $G_1 \times G_2$ on it; we also have a differential operator $P \in \mathscr{D}(X)$. If $P$ takes $G_1 \times G_2$-invariant functions to $G_1 \times G_2$-invariant functions and also is $G_1$-invariant, is it necessarily true that $P$ takes $G_2$-invariant functions to $G_2$-invariant functions?

Would this be true if we require that $G_1$ be a connected semisimple Lie group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X$ be ${\mathbb R}\times{\mathbb R}$ and let $G_1\cong G_2$ be the group of reals, $G_1$ acting by translation on the first argument, $G_2$ on the second.
Let $f$ be any smooth function on $\mathbb R$ and let $D=f(y)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$, where the coordinates on $X$ are $(x,y)$. Then $D$ ist $G_1$-invariant. Maps $G_1\times G_2$-invariants to zero, hence to $G_1\times G_2$-invariants, but does not map all $G_2$-invariant functions to $G_2$ invariants.

Comment: Can't believe I overlooked such an obvious answer. Thanks.

Comment: This also answers my followup, simply by letting $G_1$ and $G_2$ be any group, and $D$ be equal to $f(y) D_0$, where $D_0 \in \mathscr{D}(G_1)$; then that satisfies all of the conditions.

Comment: Where $D_0$ is $G_1$-invariant, I should have said.